# Multiple proc reg from a macro variable

Tags: sas, proc

I am trying to shorten my program. I want to make multiple regressions one by one from a list of independant variables and a single dependant variable.

This is my list of variables:

```
%let depT1 = BPT1;
%let indepT1 = age POIMEST1 TAIMEST1 TUGT1 TLEV5XT1 MARCH2T1 MARRAPT1 TAMAXT1 TAMINT1;
```

This is what i'm doing right now:

```
model &depT1= age /stb;
model &depT1= POIMEST1 /stb;
model &depT1= TAIMEST1 /stb;
model &depT1= TUGT1 /stb;
model &depT1= TLEV5XT1 /stb;
model &depT1= MARCH2T1 /stb;
model &depT1= MARRAPT1 /stb;
model &depT1= TAMAXT1 /stb;
model &depT1= TAMINT1 /stb;
```

I'm trying to find a way to write it similar to the proc gplot syntax which is:

```
plot &depT1*(&indepT1);
```

Is there any way of doing so? Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't a short cut way to reference the variables and have a regression run individually for each variable. You can see an example of how to code this on this page, towards the bottom. http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/seminars/sas_macros_introduction/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform a loop over `&indepT1`. Consider the properties of `&indepT1`:

- It's a string of words
- It's space-delimited
- It ends after a certain point

Let's think of `&indepT1` as a sentence. It's a nonsensical sentence, but every sentence has a certain number of words before it ends. We can always count how many words are in a sentence until we hit some sort of end mark, and we can know exactly which position each word is by counting until we hit the end indicator. Consider the following example:

```
1   2     3     4   5     6    7   8    9  v End
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

There are exactly 9 words in this sentence. We know where the end of the sentence is because a period marks the end of most sentences in the English language. Each word is associated with a number, and represents a unique index for this specific sentence. For example, if I selected word 4 from the sentence above, I would get the word `fox`.

A sentence always has at least 1 word in it, and SAS knows where `&indepT1` ends using a hidden internal end-of-sentence indicator.  We can count how many words are in the sentence starting with the first word and ending at the end-of-sentence indicator.  Let's exploit these two concepts to select every word one-by-one from `&indepT1`:

```
%macro model(data=, x=, y=);
    %let total_words = %sysfunc(countw(&x) );

    %do i = 1 %to &total_words;
        %let selected_var = %scan(&x, &i);

        proc reg data=&data;
             model &y = &selected_var / stb;
        run;
    %end;
%mend;
```

Once this is compiled, you can input any number of variables that you want as an argument to the macro, provided it follows the sentence rules we discussed above.

```
%model(data=have 
     , x=age POIMEST1 TAIMEST1 TUGT1 TLEV5XT1 MARCH2T1 MARRAPT1 TAMAXT1 TAMINT1 
     , y=BPT1);
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks alot sir :)